When paraphrasing over several paragraphs, how to cite an ebook with chapter and section?
Here is a sample dummy text:

Davis and Jones (2020) explore different leadership styles and their
effects on employee motivation in their ebook. They highlight
transformational leadership as particularly effective in enhancing
employee engagement and fostering organizational loyalty.
Furthermore, Davis and Jones (2020, Chapter 3, Team Dynamics section)
delve into the dynamics of team collaboration within organizations.
They discuss how effective team leadership and communication
strategies can optimize team performance and achieve organizational
goals.

I am using APA 7th. Is the above text formatted correctly? I am mainly interested in the source locator, where I want to say, look in chapter 3, team dynamics section. Please note that, this is an e-book (so no page number).

I probably would write (if these paragraphs are adjacent) Furthermore, in Chapter 3 ("Team Dynamics" section), the authors explore .... ChatGPT has ruined "delve."

For PDF ebooks I tend to just use the page number given by the PDF reader if actual page numbers aren't available in the book itself.
If its in a different ebook format like EPUB, you could open it in a ebook reader like Calibre which should do the same thing as the PDF reader and give you a page number.
You could subtract the first few pages with the cover, acknowledgments, etc, from the page number given by the PDF/EPUB reader.
So if the page your on is 72 and there's 2 cover pages, just say the quote is on page 70.
Just be sure to make a note of this in your citations table to avoid confusion.
